# react container not being removed on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form that displays an error container if any errors are added to the state. There is a `handleSubmit` function that calls a `validateForm` function before sending through the ajax request.

```
getInitialState: function () {
  return {
    formErrors: []
  };
},

render: function () {
  var errors = this.state.formErrors.map(function(error) {
    return (
      <li>
        {error}
      </li>
    );
  });

  var errorContainer = (
    <ul>
      {errors}
    </ul>
  );
```

In the return block of the `render` function, there is this line to display the error container:

```
{ this.state.formErrors.length == 0 ? '' : errorContainer }
```

Inside of the `validateForm` function, I have something like this:

```
this.setState({ formErrors: [] });
var name = this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value.trim();

if (!name) {
  newErrors = this.state.formErrors;
  newErrors.push('Please add a name');
  this.setState({
    formErrors: newErrors
  });
}
```

This works in that it will add the errors to the `formErrors` key in the state, but if I then input the correct things, any "new" errors will be appended in the view to the `li` as opposed to painting a fresh error container with N-1 errors, as in that scenario I would have filled in the name field.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ke4bmqny/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parent form component controls the error state, when you pass this down to the error display child component the errors are props of that component. See [Communicate Between Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html).

Change this line to camel-case :P

```
<GroupFormErrorComponent formErrors={this.state.formErrors} />
```

And you had it almost right but your error display component doesn't and shouldn't need to copy the error into another state variable.

```
var GroupFormErrorComponent = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
      var errors = this.props.formErrors.map(function(error, index) {
        return (
          <li key={index}>
            {error}
          </li>
        );
      });

      var errorContainer = (
        <div>
          <div>
            Sorry but there are errors:
          </div>
          {errors}
        </div>
      );

      return (
        <div>
          { this.props.formErrors.length == 0 ? '' : errorContainer }
        </div>
      );
    }
});
```

PS Just a little tip on the DOMReady stuff you added to js fiddle - you didn't need it, instead just put the `<script>` part below the html (below `<div id='form'></div>`) and it will be ready.

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dL0uj9oc/3/

Comment: Ah that's the issue! The initialState was screwing it up and using the props instead of state is the fix. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no case where 'this.state.formErrors' is emptied. So I would change the lines to:

```
var newErrors = [];
if (!name) {
  newErrors.push('Please add a name');
  this.setState({
    formErrors: newErrors
  });
}
```

But it would be better if you shared a jsfiddle where people can reproduce the problem.

On a side note, may be you should get your name value from state, instead of reading from DOM (where you get the name input value).

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle link